# Some external functionalities within a webview nativescript don't work

Tags: android, ios, angular, webview, nativescript

I have a webview and within that webview I have tables that I want to export to excel, in any web browser and mobile works well, but the moment I enter it in the webview it stops working. The same thing happens when I try to make a full screen element.

**It does not work on iOS or Android**

Thank you

Angular:

```
var viewmodel = new observable.Observable({});
// Our new Observable view model for data binding
@Component({
selector: "Home",
moduleId: module.id,
templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
styleUrls:['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
// variable para definir la url a la que accedera el webview
public webViewSrc: string = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIDXcmXZnGY";

public viewmodel= new observable.Observable({});
//variable para comprobar si se ha cargado o no el webview o la page
public isLoading:boolean= true;
public token;

constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,private 
page:Page,private tokenService:TokenService) {
    // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
}
ngOnInit(){
    //Ocultamos la cabecera que tendria la app
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
}
//evento que salta cuando comienza a cargarse la pag web
// es necesario para poder acceder a la localstorage, desabilitar las toolszoom...
onWebViewStartLoaded(args){
    const webView = args.object;

    if (webView.android) {
        webView.android.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.android.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.android.setWebChromeClient(new android.webkit.WebChromeClient());

    }
}
// Una vez cargado el webview 
onWebViewLoaded(args){

}
//Una vez cargada la Pagina no el webview!
pageLoaded(args: EventData) {
    this.page = <Page>args.object;`enter code here`
    this.page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
    this.page.bindingContext = viewmodel;
    this.token=this.tokenService.recuperarToken();
    console.log("esto tiene mi token recuperado",this.token);

}
}
```

HTML

```
<GridLayout >
<Page (loaded)="pageLoaded($event)" actionBarHidden="true">
<WebView  #myPage [src]="webViewSrc" 
(loadStarted)="onWebViewStartLoaded($event)" . 
(loadFinished)="onWebViewLoaded($event)"></WebView>
</Page>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **WebView !== Browser**, to download the exported file you will have to implement [setDownloadListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDownloadListener(android.webkit.DownloadListener)) on Android, for iOS you will have to implement the delegates and handle the download request, write the file to storage.

Also you will have to modify your layout on request so your WebView can go full screen when requested.

If it's a embedded web page within app, I think you could use [nativescript-webview-interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-webview-interface) plugin, so you could simply fire an event from your web page than handling listeners / delegates.

Comment: thank you very much manoj.
I will try to implement it.
When I try, I will publish the solution.
Thank you

Comment: Hi Manoj,

I have managed to download files from urls, but I can not download blob files
I get the following error:
"Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: blob:https://................................."


I am following the indications of this forum:

https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/download-file-in-webview-chromclient/6801/15
in others sites talks about addinterfacejs but i dont know use it
thanks

Comment: Thanks for the -only- answer @Manoj reward for you :)

Comment: @sel_calleja: could you please publish the solution here that how you have achieved download file on iOS nativescript webview. Thanks in advance